# disable syntax highlighting in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, syntax-highlighting, eclipse-cdt

I want to turn off syntax highlighting in eclipse (CDT, if it mattes).

I tried Window->Preferences->C/C++->Editor->Syntax Coloring and unchecked "Enable semantic highlighting"
I also tried Window->Preferences->C/C++->Scalability->Disable syntax coloring in editor.
Neither is doing anything for me.

How do I get regular black on white text for .c and .h files in eclipse's text editor?

Answer (score 0):

You can open the files with Eclipse text editor (no syntax highlighting no completion, etc...):

- you can change default file association in Eclipse preferences (General ->Q Editiors -> File associations)
- you can open a file with the text editor via the contextual menu on the file "Open with -> text editor". Eclipse will remember your choice, and will use the text editor the next time you'll open this file.

Comment: I like completion and other .c/.h file related customizations. I just do not like syntax highlighting, I want it off for almost all file types.
Is there still a way to retain all file type customization, but turn off just the syntax highlighting?

Answer (score 0):

Scalability mode works for me (on Eclipse CDT Luna) when I follow these steps:

1. Select Window->Preferences->C/C++->Scalability->Disable syntax coloring in editor
2. Set Window->Preferences->C/C++->Scalability->"Enter scalability mode when the number of lines in the file is more than" to something low (e.g. 10)
3. Close the file and reopen it.