# Get rid of highlighting in Eclipse IDE as shown in the attached image

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, ide, disable

I am not sure why eclipse is highlighting the code. which is making weird to look.
Is there any settings to get rid of it?
[image with code highlighting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPODL.png)

Comment: Does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/13748973

Comment: @Julia But it makes the whole file look as a text file. that does not help while looking into code.

Comment: My apologies, I misunderstood your question.

Comment: @Julia no problem. thanks.

Comment: Please do not crop the screenshot. At least the left and right rulers have to be shown.

Comment: The background color for error and warning markers is what does this. You can change in preferences or disable errors/warnings for that type of file. You can delete markers in the Problems view to see them go away.

Answer (score 1):

You hit the coverage tab by accident press alt shift j

Comment: nope it does not help.

Comment: dude i was just joshin, i was saying that not using keyboard shortcuts is for nerds, when it is obviously the other way around. sorry it didn't come off the way I wanted it to, no hard feelings I'm pretty nice in comparison to the rest of the people on here that's for sure.